# iOS Sandbox - Securing the data in Documents directory

Tags: ios

There are some files that I want to download and store in the sandbox. However, they must stay secure (i.e. encrypted) all the time. Now, I can encrypt them while downloading to the Documents itself. But when the files need to be consumed I have to decrypt them before that. The question is where to put these decrypted files?

tmp - Looks like a good place to keep it, but then what if the contents are deleted when the app has been kept minimised for days.

Documents - Keeping the decrypted file here in a separate place may not be a very good idea. It is not automatically cleaned up when the app is relaunched and if the device runs out of battery while the app is still running, these decrypted files will get exposed.

So the moot question is what the best way to ensure Documents directory's data security.

Comment: You don't really want a decrypted file anywhere as it defeats the point of the protection. You really just want to read the data into memory...

Comment: So how would that be. Say I have got an encrypted mp4 file in my sandbox's Documents directory. Now, when I want to play this local encrypted mp4 file using a MPMoviePlayerController, how to go about it.

Comment: I didn't say it was always possible (or easy). Just that you should know the security implications of what you're trying to do. You can't make it 100% secure.

Comment: I just want to know what is the maximum security that can be achieved :) You had me interested by saying it should be in memory, which made me think there is something you are implying which I may not have thought of. So let me put it this way, how would you go about ensuring the best possible security in this situation.

Comment: Rather what exactly did you mean by 'read data into memory'?

Comment: I haven't ever tried this, but guess might be to setup your app as a streaming server so that you can provide a 'callback' URL to the movie player and read and decrypt parts of the data as requested. It may still be saved to disk at some point in time. And not sure how easy any of that will be (partial decryption and server implementation...).

Comment: It is already a streaming server. There is now a need to download the files locally as well so that they can be viewed offline too.

Answer (score 0):

One useful aspect of UNIX-based systems is that you can create/open a file and then immeditely delete the file.  The file won't be accessible from outside the app, however the app will be able to read/write data to the file and the file will not actually be deleted until the file handle is closed.

This means you can create/open the decrypted file anywhere within the app's accessible file structure.

While I haven't tested this under iOS, I think there is a good chance it will work.

Comment: But the contents is still on the disk unencrypted for another jailbroken app to find.

Comment: Yes. And it does not even require a jailbroken device to access them.

Comment: @Zaph How does another process access a file that doesn't have an entry in the directory?

Comment: On jailbroken devices one reads the device directly (/dev). It all depends on how valuable the data is to an attacker. By the same token it will be necessary to overwrite the file at close time.

Comment: @Zaph - Any answer that you may want to give to the original question?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the encrypted files in the Documents directory, encrypted with the `NSData` `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete` option.

If you feel the need to encrypt the files yourself and then decrypt only as needed save the decrypted files in the Documents directory, encrypted with the `NSData` `NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete`. Add the "do not back up" extended attribute to the file. On app launch/wake, etc, based on the police overwrite files that are no longer needed and delete. Use AES, CBC mode with a random iv, random key and keep the key in the Keychain.

An option to open as a stream and decrypt on the fly into a buffer, if this works for your app.

But the catch is I really don't understand you full use-case. Best practice: Hire an iOS security domain expert to advise and vet your solution, I do. Is the security worth that price, a valid question.

In explanation to my comments: I wrote an application to recover images from a corrupted HD, not all that hard.